# Difference between "ps -o" and "ps o"

Tags: linux, ps

In a script, I am trying to retrieve some details of all processes of current user on linux (RHEL 6.4 and 5.7). I was using "ps -o pid,args,euser" for it. But I realized it was not including processes owned by same user but launched in different shell session. Then I tried "ps o pid,args,euser", it works. In man page, I could not see anything which implies such difference. What causes it?

```
$ ps  -o 'pid,args,euser'
  PID COMMAND                     EUSER
13491 -/usr/bin/ksh               ak
13519 bash                        ak
25427 ps -o pid,args,euser        ak

$ ps  o 'pid,args,euser'
  PID COMMAND                     EUSER
13491 -/usr/bin/ksh               ak
13519 bash                        ak
13699 -/usr/bin/ksh               ak
13727 bash                        ak
20573 -/usr/bin/ksh               ak
20616 bash                        ak
20996 -bash                       ak
21027 screen -D -R                ak
24842 /apps/ak/localdis/pub/cpyth ak
25460 ps o pid,args,euser         ak
25714 -/usr/bin/ksh               ak
25742 bash                        ak
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To quote from the man page (available [here](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?ps) via first result on Google)

> ```
>   ... The use of BSD-style options will also change the process
>   selection to include processes on other terminals (TTYs) that are owned
>   by you; alternately, this may be described as setting the selection to
>   be the set of all processes filtered to exclude processes owned by
>   other users or not on a terminal. These effects are not considered when
>   options are described as being "identical" below, so -M will be
>   considered identical to Z and so on.
> ```

Comment: I think this is it. o without a dash is (as explained earlier in the man page) a BSD-style option.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure but it may be due to the ambiguity between sort order and formatting.

Details can be found [here](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/ps1.html):

> O order Sorting order. (overloaded)
>
> The BSD O option can act like -O (user-defined output format with some common fields predefined) or can be used to specify sort order. Heuristics are used to determine the behavior of this option. To ensure that the desired behavior is obtained (sorting or formatting), specify the option in some other way (e.g. with -O or --sort).
>
> For sorting, obsolete BSD O option syntax is O[+|-]k1[,[+|-]k2[,...]]. It orders the processes listing according to the multilevel sort specified by the sequence of one-letter short keys k1, k2, ... described in the OBSOLETE SORT KEYS section below. The "+" is currently optional, merely re-iterating the default direction on a key, but may help to distinguish an O sort from an O format. The "-" reverses direction only on the key it precedes.